# Include node at end point tikz decorations

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the `decorations.markings` tikz library to place circles evenly along a path:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.2 with {\fill circle(2pt);}
    }
]
    \draw [postaction={decorate}, color=black] (0,1) to[out=30, in=100] (2,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code above produces

[image]

which doesn't include a node at the end point of the curve. Increasing the end point position (e.g, changing 1 to 1.2, 1.3, 100, etc.) doesn't change the output.

How do I include the circle at the end without manually placing a circle node at that coordinate?

Comment: It's the precision problem of `0, 0.2000001,...,`. Try `0 and 1.01` in the decoration

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Further, the issue remains when I use a step that can be represented exactly in floating point, e.g., `0.25`  or `0.125`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As percusse says, this seems to be a rounding problem. Using a step of `0.1999` produces the expected output:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.1999 with {\fill circle(2pt);}
    }
]
    \draw [postaction={decorate}, color=black] (0,1) to[out=30, in=100] (2,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Amusingly, using a step of `0.19999` again leads to the image in the OP.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced of the rounding error argument, since there should be no rounding error for `step 0.25` since this can be represented exactly in floating point, and yet `step 0.25` leads to the same problem. Of course, I am ignorant of how the text `step 0.25` is eventually converted to a float, and this process may very well introduce rounding errors. Anyhow, this answer clearly provides a working solution to get the desired result, which is all that matters for me in the end!

Comment: @Chester I think that the (rounding?) error comes from putting a point on the curve, so the step is going to be "deformed" from the "nice" number `0.25` into something that does not have a "nice" floating point expression. This is, however, just a guess because I don't know anything about what the `tikz` code actually does.